# Fancybox 1.3.4 not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I have an .swf movie embedded in fancybox on this site: http://www.courtyarddental.co.uk

This works as expected in all browsers except IE, where I just get the greyed-out screen but no pop-up box.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Which page? Gallery.php looks good under IE9.

Comment: The homepage, index.php - (click the play button/image on the right hand side to initiate the fancy box.) Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an old issue and we never knew exactly what was the reason. Basically fancybox v1.3.x won't display "object" elements with "data" attribute (IE6/7/8) like in your code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="the_courtyard.swf" width="640" height="360">
```

you can see the old thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/6f97d8422f5b126e/) back in January 2010

additionally, linking inline content has other issues;
see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33/)

I would recommend you to link the video directly like

```
<a href="http://www.courtyarddental.co.uk/the_courtyard.swf" id="movie"><img width="207" height="117" border="0" title="Play the video" alt="Play the video" src="http://www.courtyarddental.co.uk/images/video-btn.png"></a>
```

and use this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#movie').fancybox({
    'padding': 0, //optional
    'width': 640, 
    'height': 360,
    'type': 'swf',
    'autoScale': false
    });
});
```

that works fine for most browsers including IE7+

a demo [here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/issueWithDataAttribute_1dec11.html)

Answer (score 0):

SWF loads and plays fine for me under **IE 9.0.8112.18641**, **Flash player 11.0.1.152**. (Does not auto-start, I need to click the swf play button to start the movie.)

Possible caching issue?

Also, your box doesn't appear to be large enough; I am seeing both horizontal and vertical scrollbars for the div containing the SWF.