# Fancybox swfobject "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Tags: jquery, fancybox, swfobject, jwplayer

Ok I have installed FB 2.0.x and it's really nice. But, I have a page with 4 videos on it using the JW Player. Currently, when you click on a link it runs a function to open a fancybox instance. The fancybox is a set of HTML code. Inside the html code is a div with an id (unique for each div/video). Then, it adds the flashvars, params and attributes. The function is below:

```
function show_modelpopup(id,title,filepath,base_url) {
    var flashvars = { file: base_url+"uploads/videos/original/"+filepath, autostart:'true', skin: base_url+'js/skin.zip'};
var params = { allowfullscreen:'true', allowscriptaccess:'always', wmode: 'transparent'  };
var attributes = { id: id+'player', name: id+'player' };                             
swfobject.embedSWF(base_url+'mediaplayer/player.swf','container'+id, 480, 385, '9.0.115', 'false', flashvars, params, attributes, flashloaded);
}
```

And when the flashvars, params and attributes are done being setup, it runs swfobject.embedSWF and the last option is the function to run when it's done loading the video:

```
function flashloaded() {
    jQuery('#shadowbox_archives').fancybox({
        padding: 10,
        type: 'html',  
        height: 520,
        width: 600
    });
    jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#shadowbox_archives'));
}
```

And this all works GREAT. It loads the window and you see the flash player. But when you click the play button it gives "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.". I'm using firebug on Firefox to console log things and I verified the flv file path IS correct. In fact, I have the homepage set to display the very same video but not inside the fancybox. The output from the swfobject js are below:

Fancybox Popup:

```
    <object id="45player" width="480" height="385" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="45player" data="http://www.green-scene.com/mediaplayer/player.swf">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www.green-scene.com/uploads/videos/original/video_45_1318559535.flv&autostart=true&skin=http://www.green-scene.com/js/skin.zip">
    </object>
```

Home Page (non fancybox):

```
    <object id="45player" width="480" height="385" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="45player" data="http://www.green-scene.com/mediaplayer/player.swf">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www.green-scene.com/uploads/videos/original/video_45_1318559535.flv&autostart=true&skin=http://www.green-scene.com/js/skin.zip">
    </object>
```

The home page has no issues. But the fancybox does. So what am I missing?

I appreciate all your help!

**UPDATE** Interesting discovery just made. If I click the button in the player control bar to expand to full screen, it will go full screen and I can click play to actually play it. If I click the button to return to normal size (or hit esc) it continues to play in the fancybox. But then if I try to click pause it disappears and gives me the same error message.

**UPDATE #2** Turns out the Internet Explorer likes the above and it works just fine. But Firefox and Safari give me the same error above. It's mind boggling.

**UPDATE #3** I was able to get the video to autoplay when the shadowbox opens, but now you can't pause or go fullscreen in Firefox or Safari on Mac. But IE 8/9 still work just fine.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a link with the issue, otherwise we will be guessing

Comment: Sure. Go here first: http://www.green-scene.com/index_demo.php and click Login at the top. Use the following login info: helpme / stackoverflow. Then go here: http://www.green-scene.com/index_demo.php/myscene/archives. You will see 4 video thumbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I had a look at your page and I saw that each thumb fires a function onclick:

```
onclick="return show_modelpoup('//parameters')"
```

the function `show_modelpoup()`, which is located inside the [archives.js](http://www.green-scene.com/system/application/frontend/views/includes/js/archives.js) file builds the content of a DIV with `id="shadowbox_archives"` via jQuery html()

```
jQuery('#shadowbox_archives').html();
```

**but** also binds Fancybox to the same selector

```
jQuery('#shadowbox_archives').fancybox();
```

... later, the same function fires Fancybox (no shadowbox) with the API method `$.fancybox.open()` ... so far so good !?!?

What is happening here is that the actual content inside of Fancybox is a DIV with `id="shadowbox_archives"` (also bound to Fancybox), so every time you click on any part inside of such DIV, either your swf controls or elsewhere (even on an empty space) it tries to fire Fancybox again (with no indication of what the content should be this time) hence the error "*The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.*"

Binding Fancybox to the same content (selector) that will be opened in Fancybox creates a loop effect, so you would need to re-formulate your `show_modelpoup()` function to change that,

... or maybe you just need to modify the `flashloaded()` function (inside `show_modelpoup()`) in a way that it does directly fire Fancybox after the flash content has been loaded, like:

```
function flashloaded() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        href: '#shadowbox_archives',
        padding: 10,
        type: 'html',  
        height: 520,
        width: 600
    });
    // jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#shadowbox_archives'));
}
```

Notice that I commented out the API method `$.fancybox.open()`

**UPDATE**:

Since you are using inline content, your `flashloaded()` function should look like:

```
function flashloaded() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        href: '#shadowbox_archives',
        autoSize: false,
        padding: 10,
        type: 'inline',  // no html
        height: 520,
        width: 600
    });
    // jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#shadowbox_archives'));
}
```

Comment: Ok. I think I understand what you are getting at. However, I was having trouble getting the fancybox to even open without adding the api open method. So I modified it as you suggested and now when I click a thumbnail, I get that error. One thing I realized right before I got your message is that if I click ANYWHERE inside the shadowbox except for the padded edge, it would do the same thing as clicking on the video. So it was like there was a layer over the top. But it makes sense what you said because IE doesn't like div "click" events, but FF and Safari does. I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: OK, I just noticed I overlooked something ....replace: type:'html' by type: 'inline' ... and add autoSize: false to your API options, I think type:html is creating the problem

Comment: You should set type:'html' along with the API option "content" only like: content: '<span>hardcoded content</span>'

Comment: That was great! That did it. Sheesh. Thank you so much!!

Comment: don't forget then accept this as the the best answer and vote for it   ;)

Comment: I can't vote because apparently I don't have enough reputation... One more question. My client has a slightly older windows machine (XP) running IE 8 and on his machine, the video won't load. It seems to load a different version of the player (that looks more like the quicktime player control bar strangely enough) or possibly different skin. But it's not giving any errors. If you try to play the video it does nothing. On his mac, in Safari, when he clicks full screen it works but when he returns to standard size the video disappears for a bit but the sound keeps going. Ideas on either problem?

Comment: Personally, I don't like to play swf videos in fancybox the way you do on the Green Scene website (via object tag / parameters). I would rather prefer to link directly the videos within my anchor tag and attach all the parameters in the URL. I know you are using Fancybox v2 but maybe this thread (is Fancybox v1.3.x) will give you an idea what I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8347309/1055987 .... that normally solves many known or potential issues.

Comment: I would do it that way, but we need the title and the favorite link inside the window. So we have to run html with the video in it. What's strange though is that if I am not using the Fancybox system the video stuff works just fine. But inside of Fancybox, I have these issues with IE and such. I love the version 2 Fancybox and appreciate all the work that went into it. Just looking for some ideas on how to fix this. Thank you.